# Operand should contain 1 column when joining tables with update

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I'm trying to update a table by combining two queries as follows

```
 UPDATE result, games_played
      SET result.precentage_correct =
(
SELECT user_id, 100*SUM(n_win)/SUM(n_total) AS pct_win FROM
(SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS n_win,
  NULL AS n_total
  FROM games_played
  WHERE winner != 'n'
  AND game = 1
  GROUP BY user_id
  UNION SELECT user_id, NULL AS n_win,
  COUNT(user_id) AS n_total
  FROM games_played
  WHERE game = 1
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS counts
GROUP BY counts.user_id
)
WHERE result.user_id = games_played.user_id
```

However I get the error

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong... I can select the result as a new table

SQL fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5374e6/1

Comment: Dont select user_id, just pct_win. The error mesaage means you try to update one column(percentage_correct) with 2 values/columns

Comment: Thanks I now see why I get this error however I tried this but I get the error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: check my answer for that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add filter criteria in your subquery. The error 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' as you mentioned in comment means the subquery (the one you named AS counts) returned more than one result. Something like this:

```
UPDATE result, games_played
      SET result.precentage_correct =
(
SELECT 100*SUM(n_win)/SUM(n_total) AS pct_win FROM
(SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS n_win,
  NULL AS n_total
  FROM games_played
  WHERE winner != 'n'
  AND game = 1
  GROUP BY user_id
  UNION SELECT user_id, NULL AS n_win,
  COUNT(user_id) AS n_total
  FROM games_played
  WHERE game = 1
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS counts
GROUP BY counts.user_id
HAVING counts.user_id = result.user_id
)
WHERE result.user_id = games_played.user_id
```

Comment: thanks for both providing answer and stating what I was going wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the logic of your query but you can fix the syntax error by actually using the query as a table by aliasing it in the source tables list.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/436eb/1

```
UPDATE result, games_played,
  (SELECT t1.user_id, 100*SUM(t1.n_win)/SUM(t1.n_total) AS pct_win FROM
   (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS n_win, NULL AS n_total
     FROM games_played
     WHERE winner != 'n' AND game = 1
     GROUP BY user_id
    UNION 
    SELECT user_id, NULL AS n_win, COUNT(user_id) AS n_total
     FROM games_played
     WHERE game = 1
     GROUP BY user_id
   ) AS t1
  ) AS counts

SET result.precentage_correct = counts.pct_win
WHERE result.user_id = games_played.user_id
```

Comment: thanks, but this dosen't actually work it updates all users in results with a value of 63...

Comment: That would be another question. You had a syntax issue. Now it appears that your query is also flawed in its logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `UPDATE`. See the [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6787f/1):

```
UPDATE result
SET result.precentage_correct =
    ( SELECT 100*SUM(winner <> 'n')/COUNT(*) AS pct_win
      FROM games_played
      WHERE game = 1
        AND result.user_id = games_played.user_id
    ) ;
```

Or with a query more like your logic. This is even better because (unlike the previous) it will not `UPDATE` the whole `result` table (with Nulls for those users that have no games played) but only those users that have at least one result in the `games_played` table. Tested at [SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e38ae/1)

```
UPDATE result AS r
  JOIN
    ( SELECT user_id, 
             100*SUM(winner <> 'n')/COUNT(*) AS pct_win
      FROM games_played
      WHERE game = 1
      GROUP BY user_id
    ) AS gp
    ON r.user_id = gp.user_id
SET r.precentage_correct = gp.pct_win ;
```